# Column overwrite when using dtypes in read_csv?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have an example.csv that looks like

```
col1, col2, d, e
aa,1,bb,2
bb,2,aa,1
cc,3,dd,3
```

and I do

```py
import polars as pl
dtypes = {
    'car' : pl.String,
    'game' : pl.Int32,
    'house' : pl.String,
    'bob' : pl.String
}
df = pl.read_csv(
    "example.csv",
    dtypes=dtypes
)

print(df.columns)
```

The ouput is:
['car', 'game', 'house', 'bob']

Which is overwriting the column names from the csv which is no the behavior I was expecting

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13574

Answer (score 1):

`Polars` uses the first row as the header row by default, which means it treats the first row as the column names. But if you specify a `dtypes` dictionary with keys that do not match the column names in the CSV file, `Polars` will use the keys from your `dtypes` dictionary as the column names instead. **If you want to maintain the original column names from your CSV file and still use the `dtypes` dictionary for specifying data types, you need to ensure that the keys in your `dtypes` dictionary exactly match the column names in your CSV file.**
Here's the corrected part of your code, modify this according to your other columns too:

```
import polars as pl

# Correct data types matching the CSV-file column names
dtypes = {
    'col1': pl.Utf8,
    'col2': pl.Int32,
    'd': pl.Utf8,
    'e': pl.Int32,
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! this is somewhat of an unexpected behavior, you would expect that the key, value idiom of the dictionary is used to assign the right data type to the right column

Comment: I don't see why you would find this as unexpected. `'car', 'game', 'house', 'bob'` this columns wasn't even there in your csv file in the first place, so `polars` treated them as if you wanted to reassign the column names

Comment: @MusabbirArrafi that is, frankly, very unexpected behavior. On what basis are column names even assigned?  Apparently, by position. But that is really a dubious choice when the input is a mapping. The ideal behavior here would be for the function to *error*. Bad design

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. didn't think from that perspective

Comment: What are 'car', 'game', 'house', 'bob' supposed to represent, if not new column names?

Comment: I think, the OP expected `polars` to throw an exception or maybe adding new columns with the supplied name. Not, overwriting existing ones

Comment: `dict`s being ordered has been a standard feature since Python 3.7 so it seems perfectly reasonable for a library with a minimum Python version of 3.8 to expect the order to matter.

Comment: well, that was my first impression too

Comment: someone ended up creating an issue on the discord about this